# Python - Phoenixdb is not returning column name with value instead it is returning list of values (row)

Tags: python-3.x, hbase, apache-phoenix

i am using [phoenixdb](https://python-phoenixdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library in python to fetch data from hbase, then after running sql queries, data is returning list of row values.

For example:
when i run the following query.

```
cursor.execute("Select * from user")
cursor.fetchall()
```

result is showing

```
[abc@any.com, 9876543120, 26, 12-12-1976]
```

instead of something like dictionary or associated array so that we can know key and value i.e., column name and its value

```
[email=>abc@any.com, phone=>9876543120, age=>26, dob=>12-12-1976]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the results in the dictonary structure, set the cursorFactory while creating the cursor:

```
cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=phoenixdb.cursor.DictCursor)
```

Comment: it works! but when i try to access `data["Email"]`. It throws the error `list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: yeah, because fetchAll() will return a list. And columns are attribute of a list item. Hence you have to iterate the result list or use index.

Comment: Yeah Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, feel free to upvote or accept the answer if it helps :)